# Unable to interpolate color while moving object

Tags: react-native, interpolation, react-animated

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Animated } from 'react-native';

const ANIMATION_DURATION = 250;

class Ball extends Component {
  
  componentWillMount() {
    this.position = new Animated.ValueXY(0,0);
    this.borderC = new Animated.Value(0);
    
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(this.position, {
        toValue: { x: 200, y: 500 },
        duration: ANIMATION_DURATION
      }),
      Animated.timing(this.borderC, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
      })
    ]).start();
  }
  
  
  render() {
    const styl = {
      ball: {
        height: 60,
        width: 60,
        borderRadius: 30,
        borderWidth: 30,
        borderColor: this.borderC.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: ['green', 'yellow'],
        })
      }
    }
  
    return (
      <Animated.View style={this.position.getLayout()}>
        <View style={styl.ball}/>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}



export default Ball
```

I have a simple component which trying to move the ball from one point to another point, and at the same time changing the color from green to yellow. There is no error being thrown and the ball does move. However I couldn't figure out which part could've gone wrong.

I've implemented `Animated.parallel` in order to have both the animation running together and implemented `interpolate` at `borderColor` with `inputRange` of `1 and 0` as well as `outputRange`

This is the [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/SkuFBfrxm) for you to play around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `View` component that needs the `border-color` transition should be a `Animated.View` too.

**Sample**

```
  render() {
    const style = {
      ball: {
        height: 60,
        width: 60,
        borderRadius: 30,
        borderWidth: 30,
        borderColor: this.borderC.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: ['green', 'yellow'],
        })
      }
    }

    return (
      <Animated.View style={this.position.getLayout()}>
        <Animated.View style={styl.ball}/>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I thought they are both mixed under `this.position.getLayout` and can be rendered together. Apparently needed to treat both animation on different view